# Invalid character error SQL, OracleDataReader

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

The code stuck in

```
    OracleDataReader reader = inst.Command.ExecuteReader();
```

with an  error ORA-00911: invalid character (in query) . I have checked the query separately its working. Please guide

```
    public DataSet Get_CurrentTask(Employee emp)
    {
        if (inst.isConnected == true)
        {
            string query = "SELECT employees.empl_id, employees.emp_name FROM employees  LEFT  JOIN TASK_SUM   On employees.empl_id= TASK_SUM.emp_ID;";  
            Database inst.Command = new System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand(query, inst.getConnection());
            inst.Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            OracleDataAdapter da= new OracleDataAdapter(inst.Command);
            OracleCommandBuilder cb = new OracleCommandBuilder(da);
            OracleDataReader reader = inst.Command.ExecuteReader();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
        }
        return ds;
    }
```

Comment: can you show the complete exception with stack trace

Comment: I think the semicolon at the end of SQL statement must not be. i.e. `string query = "SELECT employees.empl_id, employees.emp_name FROM employees  LEFT  JOIN TASK_SUM   On employees.empl_id= TASK_SUM.emp_ID";`

Comment: i think you have to delete semicolon which is at the end of query.

Comment: Thanks , it worked by deleting the semi colon from the end of query

Answer (score 5):

you have to delete semicolon at the end of query string. because Oracle command method automatically add semicolon to the end of query string.

so,

```
   public DataSet Get_CurrentTask(Employee emp)
{
    if (inst.isConnected == true)
    {
        string query = "SELECT employees.empl_id, employees.emp_name FROM employees  LEFT  JOIN TASK_SUM   On employees.empl_id= TASK_SUM.emp_ID";  
        Database inst.Command = new System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand(query, inst.getConnection());
        inst.Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        OracleDataAdapter da= new OracleDataAdapter(inst.Command);
        OracleCommandBuilder cb = new OracleCommandBuilder(da);
        OracleDataReader reader = inst.Command.ExecuteReader();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
    }
    return ds;
}
```

will have to work.

Comment: It worked by deleting the semi colon from query. Thanks